# Take X number of values from RDD per label

Tags: python, apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD that looks like this:

```
[Row(label=1,data='asd'),
Row(label=2,data='asd'),
Row(label=1,data='asd'),
Row(label=3,data='asd'),
Row(label=4,data='asd'),
Row(label=3,data='asd'),
 ....
]
```

The number of samples I have for each label is not very even and I would like to get a fixed number of each label into an RDD. Is that possible?

If each one was a list, it would look like this in python:

```
agg = []
number_from_each = 5
for label in data:
    [agg.append(x) for x in data[label][:number_from_each]]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How many different labels do you have ? and do you know all of them ?
Do you want exactly 5 (and risking going thought the whole list that I assume to be very long ?

- I assume that your list of `Row` is named `data`
- I assume that your `Row` objects can call label through `Row.label`
- I assume that you have a list of know labels `labels`

An idea would be to use a dictionary to keep count of what you have already.

```
labels = [1, 2, 3, 4]
agg = []
dic = {}
for l in labels:  # Initialize the dictionary
    dic[l] = 0 
for row in data:
    if dic[row.label] < 5:
        dic[row.label] += 1
        agg.append(row)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I am looking how to do this with spark RDD, not just in python.